# What is the mathematical symbol to use in scientific documents to indicate a threshold?

Tags: inequality, notation

I'm writing my MSc thesis in Aerospace Engineering and I need a symbol to use in my equations to indicate some thresholds. I try to explain better.
I performed a computer simulation where my simulation constraints are: 1) the magnitude of the velocity difference is less than a fixed value (i.e. my first threshold); 2) the error between two angles is less then a fixed value (i.e. my second threshold).

$$\Delta V < threshold_{vel}$$
$$\Delta \omega < threshold_{ang}$$

Can you suggest symbols to indicate the tolerances at the RHS of the above inequalities?

Comment: There is no universal symbol. Letters like $M$ are often used (denoting "maximum", i.e. saynig $x<M$ means $x$ is smaller than a maximum of $M$).

Comment: Probably it is a good idea to use something with $V$ for the first and with $\omega$ for the second. For example, $V_0$ and $\omega_0$, or $\tilde{V}$ and $\tilde{\omega}$, or $V_M$ and $\omega_M$ ($M=$maximum), or $V_e$ and $\omega_e$ ($e=$ error), or $M_V$ and $M_\omega$, or $E_V$ and $E_\omega$, etc.

Comment: In general , I have come across : $V_{th}$ for Voltage Threshold ,  $I_{th}$ for Current Threshold , $v_t$ or $u_t$ for Velocity Threshold , $\theta_T$ for Angle Threshold , Etc. Most Common I have seen is : $X_{th}$ , next $X_t$ & last $X_T$.